# Python Selenium, I can't fill this input field, keys are sent and visible, but they're gone after I do something else

Tags: python, selenium

so I have a website to enter new products.

When I open that input from my browser, no problem it just works fine.

But when I open that with selenium browser, I can send_keys(), but can't do more. I know I couldn't explain it, but you will definitely understand my problem when you see the video.

Video of that input type: https://youtu.be/2ZqKzxeULyk 10 seconds

Video of the problem part: https://youtu.be/MTTn8RBwa40 10 seconds

I've tried pressing enter once, twice and clicking the input

code used in the video:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product_attributes']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input") ## CLICK ON INPUT
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product_attributes']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input").send_keys(color)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product_attributes']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

This also did not work

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span[5]/span/span/ul/li")))
```

Edit: solved the problem by clicking the dropdown list item with element.click()
thanks for help

Comment: You could try adding a couple of seconds of `wait` between the calls to let the site work on the background before new inputs.

Comment: Since they are dynamic dom elements - use expected conditions and relative XPath './' and not '//' from static dom elements … also you could try to use "select" instead of "click"

Answer (score 0):

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product_attributes']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input").send_keys(color,Keys.ENTER)
```

could you try the below xpath , i think when you send keys to field separately it replaces the enitre content in that input field , so if you wnat to type somehting and then press enter you have to do it as "string"+key

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product_attributes']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input").send_keys(color,Keys.ENTER)
```

or

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product_attributes']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input").send_keys(color+Keys.ENTER)
```

or

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product_attributes']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input").send_keys(color,Keys.TAB)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't change anything.